# Is it possible to make a dynamic route in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, gps

I am using a program that every 4 minutes sends me (via email) a GPS position in a format of a link to Google Maps, like so:

```
Move to N10.0700+E50.8625
Move to N10.0700+E50.8925
Move to N10.0700+E50.9225
```

I need to know two things:

1. Is it possible to make a script that takes the positions and shows them on Google Maps directly (so I don't have to enter the mail and press the link every time)?
2. Can I make a route that shows me every point I have been? (Lets say I got 10 mails, so I have 10 points—can it been shown as a route from point 1 to 10 and show me all the points in the way?)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom map in Google Maps to accomplish this.  You have the option of plotting points or using polygons to display map information. 

[How to create a custom Google map](http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62843)
[Example: Custom Google Map using polygons](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=218399718900161140031.0004bd090e52474a81cd2&ie=UTF8&t=m&ll=33.061622,-117.185669&spn=1.104886,1.757813&z=9&source=embed)

Updated response: Perhaps a feed from Google Docs would better suit your needs.
[Creating dynamic client-side maps with Google Spreadsheets](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/03/creating-dynamic-client-side-maps.html)
[Spreadsheet Wizard for map creation](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/spreadsheetsmapwizard/makecustommap.htm)

See also: Real Time GPS Tracking html/js (Stackoverflow 2010)
[Real time GPS Tracker on JUST HTML / JS and Google Maps to be run on a handphone? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305225/real-time-gps-tracker-on-just-html-js-and-google-maps-to-be-run-on-a-handphone)

Comment: this is not what I mean.
I want it to add points automatically.
every time I get new gps it will show me on the map.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I updated my answer with new links to dynamic map creation options.